# How to find the influence function of $\int_{[0,t]}(1-F_\_)^{-1}dF$,i.e., cumulative hazard function

Tags: asymptotics

The common strategy is to replace $F$ with $(1-t)F+t\delta_x$ and then expand the integral. However, I am not sure how to deal with $F_\_$. It seems different from $F$.